# JPA validation unique

Tags: java, validation, jpa

In two words: I have tables Parent and Child, which connected as One To Many(parent can has many child, child can has only one parent), I need a unique child name(column "name") in scope of specific parent, but it can be non unique in scope of all parents. Is this possible to do using validation annotation, like `@UniqueConstraint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place the unique constraint on pair (parent id, child name). That way, you get name uniqueness only in the scope of the given parent.